# How come I am getting this error when running gulp sass 'gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself'

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

How come I am getting this error when running gulp sass 'gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself'
I am trying to compile my sass for a shopify theme. But I get this error after running `gulp sass`

*Error*

```
Both the `sass` and `node-sass` packages are permitted. I added the line of code they recommended but that still did work.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

[01:12:12] The following tasks did not complete: sass
[01:12:12] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

**My code**

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const themekit = require('@shopify/themekit')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/global.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets'))
});
```

> I am using  `"gulp-sass": "^5.0.0"`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you installed sass as a dev dependency? npm i sass -D

Comment: i did using -g, without -g fixed my issue